# Easiest way to count pairs by groups? See inside for a better explanation

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
customer <- c('a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','d') 
item <- c(1,2,3,2,4,2,3,4,5) 
d <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I want to count the number of times that pairs of items are bought by the same person. For this example, items 1 and 2 were bought together by one person (a), items 2 and 3 were bought together by one person, but items 1 and 4 were bought together by zero people, items 2 and 3 were bought together by 2 people (a and c), etc.

I'd like to be able to count this and create a dataframe like:

```
item.1 <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
item.2 <- c(2,3,4,5,3,4,5,4,5,5)
count <- c(1,1,0,0,2,2,0,1,0,0)
d2 <- data.frame(item.1,item.2,count)
```

I've been searching for a solution but haven't been able to find one. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your objective? Are you trying to characterize your customers?

Comment: It is not a dupe of the link.  Please check the expectedd output

Comment: @akrun it is except for format of expected (actually it was exact dupe of my prior-to-edit deleted answer ;-) )

Comment: @src471 you can do that for the specific format: `comb_item <- combn(unique(d$item), 2); tab_d <- table(d); data.frame(``colnames<-``(t(comb_item), c("item.1", "item.2")), count=apply(comb_item, 2, function(x) sum(rowSums(tab_d[, x])==2)))`. (only one bactick around colnames though).This would give exactly your desired output.

Comment: The objective is to check what types of items are most frequently bought together, as part of an exploratory analysis.

Comment: @Cath, I get a warning with your code, "Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs". I'm not sure why this is happening but it's making it hard to tell if this solution will work for me.

Comment: it is strange because I tested it on your example data (except I renamed x/y as in your example you named your vectors customer and item) and I got exactly your desired output, with no warning

Comment: @Cath when I got to work and tried it it worked perfectly, thanks! I will try it on my larger dataset and let you know if there are issues.

Comment: @Cath tab_d[, comb_item] throws a "subscript out of bounds" error for my data. Could the size be the issue, or something else? My dim(tab_d)=117057 50 and dim(comb_item)=2 1225.

Comment: @src471 it shouldn't throw an error (this error means one of the item is not in d$item, which is not really possible) but anyway you're not supposed to do `tab_d[, comb_item]`...